# SMS/iMessage auto-responder on iOS

Tags: ios, sms, auto-responder

I was wondering if there were any way to, on an iPhone (will root/jailbreak if necessary), detect when you I receive an SMS message from a person and automatically then respond. I will not need to post this on the app store so anything violating that is not an issue. 
Personally I am more familiar with android and that is why I am asking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Autoresponder 3 should do the trick for you.